# How do I get jq to preserve bigint values?

Tags: json, integer, jq, bigint, arbitrary-precision

I have a large JSON file that contains bigints with their full values--not rounded like JavaScript loves to do by default.
We have a workaround to deal with the bigints in Node.js, but I'm trying to use jq (the command-line tool) to clean up our data.
However, when I ran jq on our JSON file, it rounded all of our bigints.

Is there a way to use jq so that it doesn't round the bigints or is there perhaps another command-line tool that works on a Mac that I may use instead?

Comment: I'm sure jq's answer will be provided, but there's an alternative as powerful tool - `jtc`. `jtc` ensures numerical values preserved exactly the way they specified and honors 100% JSON definition for numericals. PS. I'm the developer of the `jtc` tool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of right now, the best jq has to offer with respect to JSON numbers is the "master" version, which preserves the external numerical value very well.  The updates were made on or about 22 Oct 2019, and the "master" version of jq seems to be as safe to use as the most recent release (jq 1.6).

Examples using a recent "master" version:

```
    jqMaster -n -M '
    [0000,
     10000000000000000000000000000000000000012, 
     1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000012, 
     1000000000000000000000000000000000000001210000000000000000000000000000000000000012,
     0.1e123456]'
```

#### Output

```
[
  0,
  10000000000000000000000000000000000000012,
  1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000012,
  1000000000000000000000000000000000000001210000000000000000000000000000000000000012,
  1E+123455
]
```

Comment: I must point out though, that `0000` is not a valid JSON numeric (as per the [JSON rfc7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-6) and [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)) and the same could be confirmed with [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @Dmitry - Yes, it's well-known that jq is a tiny bit tolerant of not-strictly-conforming JSON input; I just wanted a couple of quick illustrations showing that the use of the decNumber library does not guarantee that the literal "external" representation is preserved.

Comment: that "a tiny bit tolerant of not-strictly-conforming JSON" represents a tiny bit of a problem when parsing streams of JSONs. e.g.: jq is fine parsing this stream of JSONs: `<<<'[]{}"abc"' jq`, however, this stream of 3 valid JSON values is not parsed properly then: `<<<'000' jq`. imho it's a bug that needs to be fixed as it introduces inconsistency in the expected results of parsing JSON streams

Comment: Here's the commit which implemented big integer numbers preservation - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/cf4b48c7ba30cb30e116b523cff036ea481459f6 .

Comment: I really didn't want to have to go through downloading, configuring, and installing jq master, but now that I did it--it wasn't that bad.  I'm on MacOS Big Sur and my version of bison was too old.  I used brew to install bison and had to configure my ~/.zshrc file to reference the new directory because brew won't replace system links (bison comes installed).

Comment: @Brandon - Did you try installing jq via brew with the HEAD option?

Comment: @peak Wow, no, I had no idea!  I'll have to tell my coworkers about it!  Thank you for asking!

Comment: @peak wow, `brew install jq --HEAD` totally worked!  Best option yet!

Comment: An 1.7 release candidate version is available, which includes the fix → https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.7rc1

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use “gojq”, the Go implementation of jq that uses unbounded-precision representation of integer literals.

In fact, except for one bug that has only been fixed in the “master” version of gojq as of this writing, gojq supports unbounded-precision integer arithmetic. The bug fix: https://github.com/itchyny/gojq/commit/7a1840289029c9c038d61274ceac9b8d307c0358

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but one that should allow you to avoid installing any external packages/libraries would be to use Python in the command line to parse the bigint the following way:

```
JSON_DATA='{"id": 8532687839421703901}'
ID=$(echo "$JSON_DATA" | python3 -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print(obj["id"]);')
echo $ID
```

Outputs the original bigint value:

```
8532687839421703901
```

Here is the python script not in a one-liner for readability:

```
import json
import sys


obj = json.load(sys.stdin)
print(obj["id"])
```

Comment: It's nice to know that python doesn't crush the number, but how do I use python to implement a jq-like clone?  Usually, I want to filter and transform JSON and that process using vanilla jq historically destroys the bigints.